# How to make new virtual field In data class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following columns in my table

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make a new field by combining all other fields but I don't want the new field in the database.

```
public partial class Address
{
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        Public String FullAddress =street+Town+PostCode+City;   // the required new field 
}
```

My question is how to properly code it?

Thanks

Comment: Will the proposed `FullAddress` property have a setter as well?

Comment: no need of setter @haim770

Comment: No It should be only a virtual field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a property without a `setter`:

```
public string FullAddress
{
     get
     {
         return this.street + " " +
                this.Town + " " +
                this.PostCode + " " +
                this.City;
     }
}
```

Entity Framework will automatically detect that it's a getter-only property  and will ignore it (as if it really was a `GetFullAddress()` method).

Comment: Thanks I got it.But now i m Facing new problem.
i m using Model First approach in EF . i alter this code in model.tt .
but this field dosnt showing in Linq quries